# Unable to open file in NetBeans

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I was doing a project in NetBeans 7.3, it asked me to update the IDE, after clicking the update and having it restarted, it wont allow me to view PHP files. Below is the screenshot:

[image: Netbeans issue]

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Update the mentioned plugins, Though it has nothing to do with User Agent like your question title

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to edit the title

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ how do you upgrade the mentioned plugins? I have been trying

Tools->plugin->update plugins, it wont work, I have also tried
Tools->plugin->Installed->Check php->Activate, still no good

Comment: Found the solution, manually updated the plugins. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a cache problem try deleting cache of netbeans.
for windows cache is located in C:\Users\username.netbeans\7.0\var\cache. Deleting this directory should clear the cache for you.